# How can I call the NSObject "class" method from gdb?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, debugging, gdb

I'm using gdb 6.3.50, the one that comes with Xcode 4.4.1. It seems to get confused by my attempts to call `class` on an object in the debugger.

```
(gdb) po [JSONObject class]
A syntax error in expression, near `]'.
```

I assume it's getting tripped up by the word "class", which must be some kind of reserved symbol, perhaps because I'm working in Objective-C++. Certainly, I can prod it into an error with identical wording if I try to use some other C keyword:

```
(gdb) po [JSONObject struct]
A syntax error in expression, near `]'.
```

There's nothing wrong with the object itself, it seems, because gdb can call other methods on it:

```
(gdb) po [JSONObject objectForKey:@"UTIMESTAMP"]
<__NSCFArray 0x89c9b0>( ...(etc.>)
```

Is there some construct, or symbol, or something, that I can put in the command line, to force gdb to treat "class" as just a selector?

Comment: tried `po (id)objc_msgSend(objc_getMetaClass("JSONObject"), @selector(class))`?

Comment: `JSONObject` is a value rather than a class (as per, e.g., `-[NSURLRequest HTTPBody]`), but something like `objc_msgSend(JSONObject,@selector(class))` does work.

Comment: it's bad practice to name your objects like this, caps are for classes. It should be jsonObject instead.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001281-1002931-BBCFHEAB is where I copied it from. But I do admit they don't really tell you what to do with variables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Objective-C messenger functions directly:

```
po (id)objc_msgSend(JSONObject, @selector(class))
```